# Convert non-zero column names to rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to convert sparse dataframe to the shape when for each ID write down non-zero column names as rows.

I've tryed using for loop with iterrows - but it's very slow and I cant use it.
Maybe someone have better ideas?

For example, Initial df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Id':['id1','id2','id3'], 'a':[0,1,1] ,'b':[1,0,1], 'c':[1,1,0]})

Id  a b c
id1 0 1 1 
id2 1 0 1 
id3 1 1 0
```

Expected:

```
Id   columns
id1    b 
id1    c 
id2    a 
id2    c 
id3    a 
id3    b
```

Comment: have a look at `melt` or `stack`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears all you want are the stacked indices, not the values. Might I suggest `set_index` and `stack`?

```
df2 = df.set_index('Id')
(df2[df2.astype(bool)]
     .stack()
     .index
     .to_frame()
     .reset_index(drop=True)
     .set_axis(['Id', 'columns'], axis=1, inplace=False))                                                                               

   Id columns
0   0       b
1   0       c
2   1       a
3   1       c
4   2       a
5   2       b
```

Answer (score 5):

using pandas `.25.0` , here is a way using [`.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
m=df.set_index('Id')
m.dot(m.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',').explode().reset_index(name='Columns')
```

---

```
   Id Columns
0   0       b
1   0       c
2   1       a
3   1       c
4   2       a
5   2       b
```

Comment: Indeed! Series.explode appeared in 0.25! Thank you, anky_91! Great solution!

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `melt` and filter with `loc`:

```
df.melt('Id').loc[lambda x: x['value'] != 0].sort_values('Id')
```

Output:

```
    Id variable  value
3  id1        b      1
6  id1        c      1
1  id2        a      1
7  id2        c      1
2  id3        a      1
5  id3        b      1
```

---

#### Update per @Oleskii comment:

```
df.reset_index().melt(['index','Id']).loc[lambda x : x['value'] != 0].sort_values('index')
```

Output:

```
   index   Id variable  value
3      0  id1        b      1
6      0  id1        c      1
1      1  id2        a      1
7      1  id2        c      1
2      2  id3        a      1
5      2  id3        b      1
```

Comment: Thanks, very pretty solution, but not very suitable for my case - I need to preserve existing 'Id' order..